# How to use node-schedule to schedule function at multiple times?

Tags: node.js

I want to run same piece of code 3 times in a day: 10 AM, 1 PM & 6 PM.

Code for running particular code at let's day 10 AM is as follows:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.dayOfWeek = [0, 6];
rule.hour = 10;
rule.minute = 0;


var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
    console.log('Yup!');
});
```

Do I need to copy paste same function 3 times or is there any way to tweak this? I can't use setInterval because intervals are not uniform.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but have you tried: `rule.hour = [10, 13, 18];`?

Comment: @MikeS Thanks, your solution worked. If you add it as answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to set the `hour` property correctly:

```
rule.hour = [10, 13, 18];
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, saved me some time. this information is not available on the documentation, i think