# node.js schedule task to occur at 9:30, 10:40, and 11:50 each day (no cron)

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I was using node-schedule (very similar to node-cron), but cron doesn't allow different hours and minutes. How can I schedule tasks like this? i.e., 9:30, 10:40, 11:50. I will probably have 9 different times, so copy-pasting my code 9 times seems bad.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883837/how-to-use-node-schedule-to-schedule-function-at-multiple-times)?

Comment: yeah its cron though so it won't work. In fact its exactly the same module I've been using and having problems with